# Probabilty and number theory

Tags: probability, number-theory

If two distinct numbers m and n are chosen at random from the set $\{1, 2, 3, \ldots 100\}$, then the probability that $2^m+2^n+1$ is divisible by $3$ is $p$. Find the value of $\lfloor1/p\rfloor$.

A test I gave some days ago had this question and I was unable to solve it. Since then I have tried many possible methods but have come up with nothing. I have a sneaking suspicion that the answer is $4$, but have not found any definite solution. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As $\displaystyle2^m\equiv(-1)^m\pmod3$ we need both $m,n$ to be even

The probability of both even is $$\frac{50}{100}\cdot\frac{(50-1)}{100}$$